# Взаимодействие компонентов React (передача переменной)

Tags: reactjs

Возникла проблема с передачей переменной, названия нового листа, из одной функции в другую.

Когда пользователи вводит данные в input (название листа) этот параметр должен передаться в функцию addList, которая прописана в app.

```html
 handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      var newvar = { name: this.state.listname};
      this.props.addList(newvar);
      this.setState ( listname: '' });
  }
```

сама функция addList прописана в app.

```html
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        **<AddList addList={this.handleAddList.bind(this)} />**
        <div id="listsDiv" className="List">
          <Lists lists={this.state.lists} items={this.state.items} addItem={this.handleAddItem.bind(this)} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

и должна выполнять следующее:

```html
    this.state = {
 **lists: [],** 
    };
  }

  handleAddList(s) {
      **this.setState = { lists: this.state.lists.concat(s.name)};**
      
  }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что переменная **name** объекта newvar не передается в функцию **addlist** и та не добавляет его в массив **Lists**, а как следствие новый лист не добавляется.

Помогите найти ошибку.

Comment: А где вы `listname` изменяете, не вижу что-то?

Comment: handleChange(e) { 
      this.setState ( { listname: e.target.value });
  }

<input  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.listname} type='text' ref='id' id='newID'></input>

onchange функция постоянносчитвает то что вводится в инпут


P.S. вопрос даже не в конректности задания listname,а в том, что при вызове this.props.addList(переменная) - не важно что за переменная была введена не происходит изменения самого списка lists заданного в app

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState` - это метод, а не свойство и его надо вызывать вот так:

```
this.setState({lists: this.state.lists.concat(s.name)});
```

а не присваивать ей состояние, как вы делаете

```
this.setState = {lists: this.state.lists.concat(s.name)};
```